# Foreach loop removing too many words

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

Can anyone help fix the problem I have with my foreach loop, what I'm trying to do is remove banned words from the search phrase, the banned words are in a database and i'm then splitting the search phrase and trying to compare the word in the phrase against the words in the banned list.

Problem is in the if else section its not hitting the banned work check.

Thanks for any help.

```
                ///
                ///Banned Word List
                ///
                string newSearchPhrase      = string.Empty;
                string bannedWord           = string.Empty;
                var BannedWords             = _IGBW.BannedWords().ToList();

                bannedWord = BannedWords.ToString();

                foreach (string searchWords in TextClean.Split(' '))
                    {
                    if (bannedWord.ToLower() == searchWords.ToLower())
                        {
                        newSearchPhrase = Regex.Replace(searchWords, bannedWord, " ");
                        }
                    else
                        {
                        newSearchPhrase = searchWords;  
                        }
                    }

                string bannedWordsRemoved = newSearchPhrase;
```

Comment: You mean to say flow is not entering foreach?

Comment: Time for a clbuttic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
bannedWord.ToLower() == searchWords.ToLower()
```

You are comparing a string to a string so if you have multiple banned words you would be testing something like:

```
"bannedword1 bannedword2 bannedword3" == "bannedword1"
```

which would never be true.

What you want is:

```
BannedWords.Contains(searchWords.ToLower())
```

or if your Banned words are not necessarily in lower case:

```
BannedWords.Select(word=>word.ToLower()).Contains(searchWords.ToLower())
```

Also, your newSearchPhrase string is always overwritten so in your last line where you set bannedWordsRemoved, it will always be set to an empty string or 1 word string.

EDIT FOR CLARITY:

```
            string newSearchPhrase      = string.Empty;
            var BannedWords             = _IGBW.BannedWords().ToList();

            foreach (string searchWord in TextClean.Split(' '))
                {
                if (!BannedWords.Select(word=>word.ToLower()).Contains(searchWord.ToLower()))
                    { 
                        newSearchPhrase += searchWord +" ";
                    }
                }

            string bannedWordsRemoved = newSearchPhrase;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies with this line:

```
bannedWord = BannedWords.ToString();
```

What you actually want is:

```
bannedWord = string.Join(" ", BannedWords);
```

However the entire method could be written in a cleaner fashion like so:

```
var bannedWords = new HashSet<string>(_IGBW.BannedWords().ToList().Cast<string>(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
var cleaned = string.Join(" ", TextClean.Split(' ').Where(w => !bannedWords.Contains(w)));
```

Comment: Hi Rich, got the following error with your code: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<string>.HashSet(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<string>)' has some invalid arguments Varaks worked ok

Comment: @CareerChange Answer updated, try now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are splitting the searchstring into words by

```
    foreach (string searchWords in TextClean.Split(' '))
```

But you are not building up a new searchstring, you only assign single words to newSearchPhrase at

```
    newSearchPhrase = Regex.Replace(searchWords, bannedWord, " ");
```

and

```
    newSearchPhrase = searchWords;
```

//jk